# Marketing Cloud Tab in SFDC

Tags: marketing-cloud, single-sign-on

Would it be possible to have a MC tab in SFDC? Or at least a tab when clicked would open marketing cloud tab in another window? 
(The user should also be logged in automatically as we are thinking about SSO)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that’s possible.

You can use Salesforce as an identity provider for single sign-on access to Marketing Cloud and access Marketing Cloud from a Marketing Cloud tab in Sales or Service Cloud.

To enable the single sign-on authentication and key management features for your account before performing this configuration, contact your Marketing Cloud account representative. Retrieve Marketing Cloud SSO data under the Single Sign-On Settings heading of Security Settings in the Administration section of your Marketing Cloud account. Click Download Metadata to access the information for your account. This process requires administrator privileges for your Marketing Cloud account.

Here’s the full hep doc: [Configure Salesforce Single Sign-On Services for Marketing Cloud](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_overview_configure_salesforce_sso_for_marketing_cloud.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null)

Comment: Much appreciated.